# Symfony: Two actions one route

Tags: php, symfony

I have controller where I have two actions: **createAction** and **showAction**.

**createAction** creates form from form class and renders it to **index.html.twig**.

**showAction** makes database query and takes there some data and renders it to **index.html.twig** (same .twig file as before).

How I can have two actions in one route? I tried to do two same routes but different name in **routing.yml**, but it doesn't work. It only renders the first one.

(Sorry, bad english)

Comment: Creating and showing are really 2 different things. Why would you have 1 route only for this? If you want to have the ability to insert records on the same page as the showAction, then you can change the showAction to 'catch' form posts where you perform the createAction.

Comment: @Stefan It is like guestbook. There is first form to send a new reply and then all messages.

Comment: Are these actions suppose to work with different http methods? For example createAction() works with POST, while showAction() works with GET?

Comment: I would go for 2 routes: domain.com/guestbook and domain.com/guestbook/write. Try not to mix up 2 different things. Symfony2 has not for nothing a strong routing mechanism.

Comment: @JakubZalas Yes. createAction() is POST and showAction() is GET.

Comment: @Stefan So you mean /write there is only form? Or what?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. Look at the answer of Jakub Zalas, that is in this situation maybe even a better approach.

Comment: @Stefan it actually make sense to have the same url for this. It is the same resource. Appending /write to an URL goes against RESTful resources, as we already have a verb for "write" as an http method (POST).

Comment: @JakubZalas Perfect explanation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have the same URL for two separate actions as long as they respond to different http verbs (POST/GET/PUT/etc). Otherwise how would you expect the router to decide which action to choose?

Learn how to define http method requirements from the [Adding HTTP Method Requirements](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements) section of the Routing documentation.

An example of annotation configuration:

```php
class GuestbookController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/guestbook")
     * @Method("POST")
     */
    public function createAction()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/guestbook")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction()
    {
    }
}
```